# Is there any programming language that provides syntactic sugar for run-time input checking of arguments?

Tags: input, programming-languages, function-declaration

I would like to be able to write a function like this:

```
print_multiple_times (Int(> 3 && <= 40) foo; String(match "^.{5}$") bar) =
    print(bar * foo)
```

That behaves like this:

```
print_multiple_times (Int foo; String bar) =
    if not (foo > 3 && foo <= 40):
        throw InputError('print_multiple_times, 'foo)
    if not (bar match "^.{5}$"):
        throw InputError('print_multiple_times, 'bar)
    print(bar * foo)
```

Comment: I think you are describing dependent types.

Comment: Pascal has subrange types: `type ThreeToForty = [3..40]`; then the first argument of `print_multiple_times` would be declared to have type `ThreeToForty` instead of `Int`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of [Racket's](http://racket-lang.org) contract system:

```
(define/contract (log10 x)
  (-> (>/c 0) real?)
  (/ (log x) (log 10)))
```

The *contract* in the code above is this line: `(-> (>/c 0) real?)`. The arrow indicates a *function contract*, which has the argument contracts followed by a single contract for the result. The contract on the argument is `(>/c 0)`, which checks that the argument is a real number greater than zero. The contract on the result is `real?`, which is Racket's built-in predicate for real numbers. A predicate can be used anywhere a contract is needed. Also, a regular expression acts as a contract that accepts strings that it matches. Racket has a rich library for producing different kinds of contracts.

Here are some good examples of using the function:

```
> (log10 10)
1.0
> (log10 250)
2.397940008672037
```

And here's an example of a contract violation:

```
> (log10 -5.0)
; log10: contract violation
;   expected: a number strictly greater than 0
;   given: -5.0
;   in: the 1st argument of
;       (-> (>/c 0) real?)
;   contract from: (function log10)
; ....
```

See [the chapter on contracts in the Racket Guide](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/contracts.html) for more details.

IIRC, Racket's contract system was partly inspired by Eiffel, but I believe Racket's contracts are far more expressive, and Eiffel contracts are broken for subclassing.

Comment: Wow, that's pretty convenient! And I'm actually already familiar with Racket (didn't know about this feature, though). I certainly should explore it more.

Answer (score 0):

In languages that provide implicit casting/type-conversion you can define types that perform the desired checks on their constructor, and boxing methods to automatically cast from literals.

(untested)

```
class Foo
{
    public Foo(int i)
    {
        if (! (i > 3 && i <= 40)) {
            throw ArgumentOutOfRangeException('i')
        }
        val = i;
    }
    public int val;

    public static implicit operator int(Foo i)
    {
        return i.val;
    }

    public static implicit operator Foo(int i)
    {
        return new Foo(i);
    }

    public void print_multiple_times(Foo foo, string bar) {
        // ...
    }
}
```